# How to implement a Discord slash command?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I can not figure out how to implement a slash command with live "feedback" similar to `/giphy`, `/xivdb`, etc. Is there no public API for this? I am using `discord.py`, but I guess that does not really matter much for this question.

I would like to register a new command `/mycommand` and show a list of search results as the user types.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible unless you hack the client with DiscordInjections or BetterDiscord sorry...

Answer (score 8):

It has finally arrived! After 3 years.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands

Comment: How do I implement it? I disn;t understand the docs ):.

Answer (score 0):

These are native commands built in to the Discord client.
There is no public API for these, and the only way to implement something like this is to modify the client, which is against [Discord's Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/terms).

Comment: It is now implemented: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands